# Is there a way to get the CLISP compiled with dynamic FFI support on Mac OS?

Tags: common-lisp, macports, clisp, quicklisp

I use clisp 2.48 (2009-07-28) on Mac OS X 10.6.4. I downloaded the clisp with 'sudo port install clisp'.

After installing [quick lisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/), I installed some packages, and most of them are OK.

However, when I tried to install "sqlite", I got the following error.

```
[1]> (ql:quickload "sqlite")
To load "sqlite":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    sqlite
; Loading "sqlite"
[package cffi-sys]
*** - CFFI requires CLISP compiled with dynamic FFI support.
```

It says that my clisp installed with mac port doesn't have FFI support.

Is there any way to get the CLISP compiled with dynamic FFI support on Mac OS X?

Comment: Well I'd answer this, but the answer is a no, at least for now. The FFI module requires ffcall which afaik cannot be built on osx currently. I've hacked on it a little bit with no luck. Until that is fixed is seems like FFI on osx will be stuck. The alt could be using libffi, but I'm not familiar enough (yet) to implement anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on 10.4, so I had to also install ffcall - I don't know if you installed it already.  When installing clisp I added +dynffi to the end and it worked for me.

`sudo port install ffcall

 sudo port install clisp +dynffi`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with 10.5 (64 bit compilation).

Comment: Thank you very much, ricaurte. Sadly, ffcall fails for me, too. Specs: MacPorts 1.9.2 / Mac OS X 10.6.6 / MacBook Pro 5,1